# How do you invoke a Runnable using Spring Framework?

Tags: multithreading, spring, autowired

I have a service that needs to invoke a runnable class.

Here are the lines of code that are being used in my service.

```
@Autowired
private LinkBrc2MemberProfile brcTask;                

// Background Task.
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor sate = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
sate.createThread(new LinkBrc2MemberProfile(user));
```

Here is my Runnable class

```
@Service
public class LinkBrc2MemberProfile implements Runnable {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LinkBrc2MemberProfile.class);

    @Autowired
    private LoyaltyDao dao;

    private Member member;

    public LinkBrc2MemberProfile() {
        super();
    }

    public LinkBrc2MemberProfile(Member member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public void run() {
        log.debug("*** Member User Name: " + member.getString("USER_NAME"));
        String emailAddress = member.getString("USER_NAME");
        Map<String, Object> map = dao.findBrcByEmailAddress( emailAddress );
        log.debug("==========================================================");

        if( ! map.isEmpty() ) {
            try {
                //a.CUSTOMER_ID, a.EMAIL_ADDRESS, b.card_no
                String customerId    = (String) map.get("CUSTOMER_ID");
                String brcCardNumber = (String) map.get("CARD_NO");

                log.debug("\ncustomerId: " + customerId + " brcCardNumber: " + brcCardNumber);
                if(!brcCardNumber.equals("")) {
                    // Add the Be Rewarded Card.
                    HashMap<String, String> userAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String brcNumber = member.getString("BREWARDED_CARD_NO");
                    if (brcNumber.equals("")) {
                       userAttributes.put("BREWARDED_CARD_NO", brcCardNumber);
                       try {
                          member.putAll(userAttributes);
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                          String errorMessage = "Unable to save user's BRC information due to: " + e.getMessage();
                          log.error("{}", errorMessage);
                       }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not seeing any errors in the log but at the same time it does not appear to be invoking the Runnable class.  Am I missing an annotation somewhere?  Are there any good examples that you can point me to, the only ones I have found use XML files to configure the runnable class I would like to use annotations.  Thanks in Advance.

I've updated my service to do the following.

Please help, my DAO is NULL so it looks like my @Autowired in my Runnable class is not wiring it in.

I've added the following bean to my bean-config.xml file.

```
<bean id="brcType" class="com.ws.ocp.service.LinkBrc2MemberProfile" scope="prototype"/>
```

I removed my @Autowired annotation and added the following to my service class.

```
ClassPathResource rsrc = new ClassPathResource("bean-config.xml");
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(rsrc);
LinkBrc2MemberProfile brcTask = (LinkBrc2MemberProfile) factory.getBean("brcType");                

SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor sate = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();               
// Set Member attribute
brcTask.setMember(user);
// Executer
sate.execute(brcTask);
```

Why is my dao still null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The runnable will throw a `NullPointerException`, since you create it yourself (using the `new` operator), instead of letting Spring create it. This obviously means that the autowired DAO attribute won't be autowired, which will lead to a `NPE` when calling `dao.findBrcByEmailAddress(...)`.

You should get your `Runnable` instance from the bean factory (as a prototype), set its member attribute, and then submit it to the executor.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly "autowire" LinkBrc2MemberProfile add a setter for my Member, then pass that into sate.createThread(brcTask);

Comment: Yes, but make sure it's configured as a prototype and not a singleton, since it has state.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet one last question, what is the annotation for prototype?  I just updated my post, please advise if this is the correct way to configure Runnable as a prototype?

Comment: That's it, but injecting a prototype inside a singleton isn't alright. Get it from the bean factory.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I accepted your answere, but what is the difference between getting it from the beanfactory vs injecting it via autowired?

Comment: If you inject a prototype into a singleton, the runnable you'll get from the singleton will always be the same instance, since the singleton is injected only once. If you get a prototype from the beanfactory, you'll get a new instance each time.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question of how to properly use a Prototype-Bean, this is my favorite way:

```
@Component
abstract class MyBean {
    /* Factory method that will be installed by Spring */
    @Lookup
    protected abstract YourPrototypeBean createBean();

    void someCode() {
        YourPrototypeBean bean = createBean();
    }
}
```

Since it's a factory method, you can create as many instances as you like.

Comment: Note that [`@Lookup`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html) works since Spring 4.1.